# Tpyedefs: how to apply this command in below case specifically

Tags: python, c#, api, cpython

C-API

Main routines for the FES prediction software.
Typedefs
FES

FES handler

typedef void* FES

https://github.com/CNES/aviso-fes/blob/main/C_API.md#c-api

I geologist using conda env to download Tide data. Need step by step guide please

Comment: A bit too broad question. They have [exmples](https://github.com/CNES/aviso-fes/tree/main/examples) in C and Python for their API. You probably would need to run this project, google for more examples or ask on aviso-fes github for more examples and tutorials (there is a contact email on their README).

Comment: Thank you frmbelz, will try and email them for more.